# How To Implement Event Sourcing & Publish Integration Event To Event Bus While Using Asp.Net Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, event-sourcing, asp.net-core-identity, clean-architecture, event-bus

In my clean architecture project I am using asp.net core identity **UserManager** class for managing users.

I have abstracted the methods of **UserManager** class to **IUserManager** interface inside the **Application Layer** of my clean architecture core project.

I couldn't figure out how to achieve **Automicity** with event sourcing and publish integration event to event bus.

Answer (score 2):

A **Domain event** can be consumed using an INotificationHandler(in MediatR).
Below is a link to a clean architecture template (written by Jason Taylor) that uses Demain Event.

https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/tree/main/src/Application/TodoItems/EventHandlers

The Masstransit system is a very simple way to produce and consume messages for **integration events**.

https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#publish

https://masstransit-project.com/usage/consumers.html#consumer